# ef core controllers without repository

Tags: .net, entity-framework, controller

I'm new to backend and dotnet. I saw the repository pattern and prons and cons about using it with ef core. So I decided not to use it. The question is, where should I put the logic which interacts with db ? Is there any way to separate it from controllers ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how big your project is, and how many different kinds of "users" (= software, not operators), your project will have.

Remember: your DbContext represents the tables in your database and the relations between the tables. If you use "code first", it also know how to create the database.

Sometimes, for efficiency reasons you might still have some SQL commands and maybe even some stored procedures.

Because they are also part of the database, these methods should also be in your DbContext.

Quite often a separate class hides that you are using a SQL database for this. For lack of a better term, and to make life difficult for you, this separate class is quite often called a repository.

Users of the repository don't have to know that you use entity framework to communicate with the database. What the hell, they don't even have to know that you use a database. All they know is that if they store something in the repository, then later they can retrieve it, even if the program has been restarted. So if you decide to save your data in a JSon file, or CSV, and read the tables as Dictionaries, users of your repository wouldn't need to notice this.

This will allow you to change your database communication method: you can use Dapper, instead of entity framework, or use traditional SQL commands. Only your repository might need to change. If you do your separations right, you might even be able to change your database tables without users having to know this.

Another advantage of a separate repository class, is that you can supply different interfaces for different users: most users only need to do queries. Only super users might need to Change / Add / Remove items, and only the administrator needs to change tables.

A third advantage of separating the repository from the DbContext is that unit tests will be a lot easier: instead of `DbSet<...>`, you can use `IDictionary<...>` to put the test data in.

For example, you  have a database with Schools, Teachers, Students, etc.

```
class SchoolDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<School> Schools {get; set;}
     public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers {get; set;}
     public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
     ...
}
```

Everyone who has access to this SchoolDbContext can mess up your database. Of course you don't want that, so you decide to create a separate repository. You can decide to create separate repositories for every type of users, or to create separate interfaces.

```
class SchoolRepository : IUserRepository, ISuperUserRepository,
    IAdminitorRepository, IDisposable
{
    private readonly SchoolDbContext dbContext = new DbContext();

    // TODO: implement the interfaces via dbContext
}
```

If you use explicit interface definitions and a factory, it is easy to give certain users only certain privileges.

```
public SchoolRepositoryFactory
{
    // TODO: do something with passwords or some other authentication method
    public IUserRepository CreateSchoolRepository(User user) {...}
    public ISuperUserRepository CreateSchoolRepository(SuperUser user) {...}
    public IAdministratorRepository CreateSchoolRepository(Administrator user) {...}
}
```

Now suppose people complain: if they have deleted an item by accident, they can't undelete it anymore.

```
ISuperUser.RemoveStudent(int studentId);
```

You decide to add a field to your student table, which you set if the Student is deleted:

```
public Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime? DeleteDate {get; set;}
}
```

Now if the Student is to be deleted, it is not really deleted, only the DeleteDate field is set. To prevent that users see the deleted Students:

```
IQueryable<Student> FetchStudents => this.DbContext.Students
    .Where(student => student.DeleteDate == null)
    .Select(student => new ...);
```

Once a month, the Administrator runs a query to remove all Students that have a DeleteDate of some time ago.

So because of the Separate repository class you can:

- Change the database without changing the interface with the users
- Change the method used to store the data, for instance user Dapper, or EF, or if you find that you won't need so much data after all: CSV, JSon, XML (unit-testing: use Dictionaries with test data)
- Give separate users separate access rights.

I think these are enough arguments to use a separate repository class. Only if you have a fairly small project, I wouldn't bother.